# Upload of large RDF/Xml file to Openrdf Sesame failing

Tags: tomcat, rdf, sesame

I'm trying to upload a 9mb .rdf ontology to the sesame workbench (through my browser - have tried Chrome and Firefox) but the upload fails every time.

I'm pretty sure it's a problem caused by the size of the file as I've tested out smaller .rdfs and they work fine. I've been getting either one of the following two errors each time:

> INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
>   {}->localhost:8080: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>
> INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
>    {}->localhost:8080: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

I get the first error when trying to upload the file itself, and the second when I try to upload the text from the file via the "Enter the RDF data you want to upload" textbox.

I've already edited the tomcat server.xml file to remove the maxPostSize as follows:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="100000" 
           redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="0" maxHttpHeaderSize="31072" />
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated - either for uploading the file or some other workaround. Here's a paste of the output if it helps: http://pastebin.com/ZAw3C2K1

Comment: Fixed it. I ran the sesame command line tools and it turns out that Java was the issue: "JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK." I added "DentityExpansionLimit=1000000" as a startup command for the sesame command line tools and tomcat and then it worked.

Comment: if this fixed your problem, you should post it as an answer, rather than a comment. That way, it will be more obvious for other people with a similar issue.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. I ran the sesame command line tools and it turns out that Java was the issue:

> JAXP00010001: The parser has encountered more than "64000" entity expansions >in this document; this is the limit imposed by the JDK.

I added `DentityExpansionLimit=1000000` as a startup command for the sesame command line tools and tomcat and then it worked.